# Term for the "nullspace" of a nonlinear system of equations

Tags: terminology

Just a quick terminology question.

The set of solutions to a **linear** system of equations with nonunique solutions is known as the "*nullspace*".

What is the equivalent terminology (if there is one) for the nonunique solutions to a **nonlinear** system of equations? (or its equivalent Groebner basis)

For example:
$$
\begin{align}
&x_{1} + x_{2}^{2} + 3x_{3}= 0\\
&x_{3} = 2
\end{align}
$$

Is there a name this set of solutions? 
The solutions of the above system is:
$$
\begin{align}
&x_{1} = -6 -t^{2}\\
&x_{2} = t\\
&x_{3} = 2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Maybe the *locus*? If the linearised system always have the same nullity, then you may even talk about the *solution manifold*.

Comment: I'm with Willie; locus sounds about right. Geometrically your nonunique set of solutions would correspond to some curve/surface...

Comment: I'm torn here: I think both Willie's and lhf's answers have merit, and I'm not sure which one I should accept. Willie, if you would care to make your comment and answer, I'd be happy to upvote (and let others do the same).

Answer (score 4):

*Zero set* is a usual term. But so is *set of solutions*. *Zero set* is applied to sets of functions. *Set of solutions* is applied to systems of equations.